# How to load image by name in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have 10 images I want to process. How do I call all those images one by one?
(Figure 1 is called-process-complete) (Figure 2 called-process-complete)
and so on. How to do this in OpenCv python? Thanks

Comment: Have you already been through this? https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is to find the files in a particular folder to later process it, if that's the case then this might help.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

files  = glob.glob("/home/User/Pictures/*.png")   #Get all files from a directory /home/username/Pictures that have an extension png

for pic in files:    #process each picture as per your api
    jpgfile = Image.open(pic)
    print jpgfile.bits, jpgfile.size, jpgfile.format
```